# How to use one scenario output to another scenario without using properties files

Tags: karate

I am working on API testing project. My requirement is to use response of one API as a response of another. I need different Feature files for each API. The challenge was to use output of one API as input to another which in my case is output of one feature file as input of another.
Also i don't want to call one feature file in another. So to achieve this currently we are using Runner class to initiate the test and using Properties file to store the responses. In the same run we are reading these properties file which act as input to another API(Feature file).

Is there any other better way to do this since we are not willing to use properties file in the framework.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Peter,I have already accepted it.Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating your tests. My advice is combine the 2 calls into one scenario. Else there is no way unless you call a second feature file.